# Error CS1061: doesn't contain a definition for `transfrom' and no extension method `transfrom' of type `PlayerControl' could be found

Tags: c#, unity, transformation

I tried finding a solution, but I couldn't find one.

I'm getting the error:

> GameManager.cs(15,46): error CS1061: Type `PlayerControl' does not contain a definition for`transfrom' and no extension method `transfrom' of type`PlayerControl' could be found

So here is under this is GameManager class.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform platformGenerator;
private Vector3 platformStartPoint;

public PlayerControl thePlayer;
private Vector3 playerStartPoint;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    platformStartPoint = platformGenerator.position;
    playerStartPoint = thePlayer.transfrom.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Under here is part of the PlayerControl class.

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {

public float moveSpeed;
public float speedMultiplier;

public float speedIncreaseMilestone;
private float speedMilestoneCount;

public float jumpForce;

private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

public bool grounded;
public LayerMask whatIsGround;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundCheckRadius;

//private Collider2D myCollider;

private Animator myAnimator;
```

I'm trying to do it, but it says this when I hover over thePlayer.**transform**.position; "Error CS0117: 'PlayerControl' does not contain a definition for 'transform'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

`transfrom` should be `transform`.